# openpyxl Make header as bold and color

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How do I create a table with headers with bold and in different color.

```
Sl.No   State   Country Code
  1     abc     abc     1
  2     xyz             2
  3     ddd     mvp     3
```

2nd row doesnt contains country value. I want to make entire row as red.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a style to the cells you want to change. See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/styles.html

Comment: Links is broken!

Comment: @user1012513, Find it here - https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html